# Team City MSTest runner exits with not zero code - Symantec

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, mstest, windows-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to set up Team City CI on Server 2012R2 
The MSTest build runner step fails to run.
**NunitLauncher.exe fails on server 2012[R2], even from command prompt**

**NunitLauncher.exe runs fine on Server 2012.**

This works fine at home on the following configuration (TeamCity 8.0.6 on Server 2012)
 At work, for some reason, this won't. (TeamCity 8.0.6 running on Server 2012[R2])

```
When executing MSTest build runner step, I see the following: (Server 2012R2, Visual Studio 2013)

    [18:40:33]Step 2/2: Run Unit Tests (MSTest) (3s)
    [18:40:33][Step 2/2] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit
    [18:40:33][Step 2/2] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\b00779c1ff5b6b7b
    [18:40:37][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 255
    [18:40:37][Step 2/2] Step Run Unit Tests (MSTest) failed

When I try and run JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe #TeamCityImplicit from command prompt I get the following error:

TeamCity .NET NUnitBootstrap has stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX
  Application Name: JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe
  Application Version: 8.0.23.0
  Application Timestamp: 527e788a
  Fault Module Name: JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.23.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 527e788a
  Exception Offset: 00005bce
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Data: 00000008
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 01d7
  Additional Information 4: 01d7340064827245f2249cd1f1a7c264

I have installed on two different servers running Server 2012 R2 with the same failed results.
I install on Server 2012 and the NUnitLauncher.exe runs without issue...

Team City Dev team, any ideas?
```

Comment: I've tracked the issue down to this:  NUnitLauncher.exe won't execute on the system. (generates App log details I posted above.

I can, however, run NUnitLauncher20.exe from the system without getting the exception.

Comment: Uninstalling Symantec Antivirus fixes the issue but does not resolve my problem as we cannot get approval to run our server without Symantec.   I've added exceptions but still does not work!!!

Comment: May be related: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5468665

Comment: I engaged with Team City, this was in fact caused by unsigned assemblies in TeamCity, here is the link to follow: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-35167

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this with SEP server side exceptions, TeamCity identified the root cause as unsigned assemblies.  Here is the URL for the TeamCity bug fix: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-35167